# Does the following limit exist $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{y}?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Does the following limit exist?

> $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{y}$

The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098821/does-the-multivariable-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-y-to-0-a-frac-sinxy) is not correct in my opinion since it does not take under consideration all the surface parts in which $y=0.$

Comment: $$y=0$$ makes no sence then in this case we get $$\frac{\sin(0)}{0}$$

Comment: @DiegoMath How can $(1,y)$ be included when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$?

Comment: @DiegoMath The limit does exist... your second path is not passing through $(0,0)$.

Comment: The expression under limit does not exceed $|x|$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ hence by definition of limit the desired limit is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Set $g(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x\cdot \sin(xy)}{xy} \quad \text{if}\quad x\neq 0\\ 0 \quad \quad \quad \;\; \text{if}\quad x=0 \end{cases}$

Then $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{y}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}g(x)=0,$$ as we can make $\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$ as close to $1$ as we wish.

Comment: The idea is just fine but you also need to address the (trivial) case when we are approaching $(0,0)$ by the line $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks @PierreCarre

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful (entire) function 
$${\rm sinc}(t):=\left\{\eqalign{{\sin t\over t}\quad&(t\ne0)\cr 1\quad\ \ &(t=0)\cr}\right.$$
with ${\rm sinc}(0)=1$, having Taylor series
$${\rm sinc}(t)=1-{1\over3!}t^2+{1\over5!}t^4-\ldots\ ,$$
and satisfying the identity $$t\>{\rm sinc}(t)=\sin t\qquad(t\in{\mathbb R})\ .$$
In terms of this function we have
$${\sin (xy)\over y}={xy\>{\rm sinc}(xy)\over y}=x\>{\rm sinc}(xy)$$
for all points $(x,y)$ where the LHS is defined, i.e., for all $(x,y)$ with $y\ne0$. For this domain we can therefore say that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\sin (xy)\over y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\bigl(x\>{\rm sinc}(xy)\bigr)=0\cdot1=0\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{y} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}x =(\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy})( \lim _{x\to 0} x)=1\times 0 =0$$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers!

I came up with another proof:

**Proof:** Since there exists a $\delta$ neighborhood of $(0,0)$, $\mathcal{B_{\delta}(0,0)}$ , in which $|sin(xy)|<|xy|$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathcal{B_{\delta}(0,0)}$, we can write for every such $(x,y)$:

> > $|\frac{sin(xy)}{y}|=\frac{|sin(xy)|}{|y|}<\frac{|xy|}{|y|}=|x| \rightarrow 0$

What you think, is it ok?

Thanks!